# Mongoose sub document prevent duplicates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoDB with a list of tricks, from which you can select your favorites.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
    }
  },
  favorites: [{
    _id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      unique: true
    },
    adv_lvl: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        default: 0,
        unique: true
    }
  }]
});
```

I've succeeded in filling favorites sub document with tricks, using findOneAndUpdate and addToSet and it won't accept adding two tricks that are exactly the same (equal id and adv_lvl), but when I send request with id of one of the array's elements, but different adv_lvl, it adds new item to the array instead of updating one that is already in. I've spent 5 hours trying to figure something out, reading both mongoDB and mongoose docs and SO questions but I am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: You need to provide snippets of code when you updating.

Comment: Can you give a reason for your structure?
Perhaps it makes more sense for you to have a tricks collection where you can define you tricks and only reference the _id in the favorites array?

This way multiple users can favourite the same trick and then you only need to update the trick in its own collection and populate favourites on users when getting them to see the updated data?  

It seems that if you want to update a trick with this structure you would need to update it across all users referencing it?

Or am I misunderstanding your goal?